# how to make a c# library invisible by main call?

Tags: c#

I want to make a c# library for my customer. But I don't want let them see the
library content. My only need is to let them use library. Not seeing my library 
code

in my Library:

```
 using System;
 using System.Collections.Generic;
 using System.Linq;
 using System.Text;
 using System.Windows.Forms;

 namespace Tcp1
 {
     public class Tcp1
    {
        public class Tcp
       {
           int a11;
           string b11;
           public Tcp(int a, string b)
           {
               a11 = a;
               b11 = b;
            }

           private  static string Add(int a, string b)
          {
              string ss = a.ToString() + b;
              MessageBox.Show(ss);
              return ss;
           }
    }
   }
}
```

I need to hide the library code from customer, And I need to support the library for my customer, But I don't want my customer to  see the content of my detailed library code. I got to hide the library code & still could be used by customer at the meantime.

I am not sure what the customer call will be, Likewise:

```
   int a;
   string b;
   string c;
   Tcp ss = new Tcp();
   c= Tcp.Add(a, b)
```

Comment: Pleas edit your code, the post is unreadable because of wrong code formatting. Also the code will not compile the way it is now. The function `Add` is out of class. Did you try to debug the code on another computer, where are no source codes for your library? By the way, unless you use a good obfuscator *(and even when you use the obfuscator)* it is still possible to see the code of your .NET application/library. Obfuscators make it only harder to decompile it, or read it, or use it. There is no simple way to completely hide your code. But in a standard way, you need to use private/internal.

Comment: Sorry for not complete code , I will update it better